# get json values and store that in my table with some specific schema

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

How can i get specific json values and store that in my table with some specific schema.

e.g i tried

```
def save_to_payment(conn,result) do
  Poison.decode!(result, as: %Payments.payment{} )
end
```

with this schema,

```
schema "payment" do
  field :payment_id, :string
  field :state, :string
  field :amount, :decimal
  timestamps()
end
```

However the actual Json has many fields, and i just require only few out of them..

I need to map the fields i want to the schema so that i save them in the database

Comment: You can pass the decoded JSON (with extra fields) through `Payment.changeset`? That will remove the extra fields and also run all the casts and validations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so you are suggesting to pass all the json to the changeset. however in order to extract the data from json in changeset can i have some example, if you like to share,  that will help. Thank you
@Dogbert

Comment: Just posted an answer that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just pass the raw decoded Map to `Payment.changeset/2` and let it handle removing extra fields and doing type casting if needed:

```
json = "{\"state\":\"CA\",\"payment_id\":1,\"go\":\"here\",\"extra\":\"fields\",\"amount\":123}"
decoded = Poison.decode!(json)
changeset = Payment.changeset(%Payment{}, decoded)
# You can now `Repo.insert!(changeset)` or use it in forms etc.
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i am getting on,
** (ArgumentError) argument error
        :erlang.iolist_to_binary{%
@Dogbert

Comment: @ZubairNabi are you sure you're passing a string to `Poison.decode!`? Can you paste the code somewhere (in your question or gist.github.com)?

Comment: Thank you, i figured it out. i was passing Json to decode, which is already a map. doesn't need to decode. Thank you 
@Dogbert